# Login failed for user sa ssis 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a problem with ssis2008

I built a package that have a connection with SQL Server authentication (username : `sa`).

When I use BI, it works fine but when I build a job that used this package it doesn't work.

I tried several solution for example change the package protection level or using xml configuration file to save password but none of them worked. Can some body help me?

Errors are:

> Log in failed for user sa

or

> Can not decrypt the password

thanks

Comment: What protection level do you have for the package ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `sa` account - not even in testing ....